# Choosing between inheritance and enum

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, types, enums

I have class Land:

```
class Land{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}
```

Land can be one of 3 types - Steepy, Plain, and Wet. Only difference among them is - when a "Tank" visits these lands, it incurs different cost based on Land type.

Now, should I create LandType enum:

```
enum LandType{
    STEEPY, PLAIN, WET
}
```

and, use it as a field in Land class?

Or, I should create 3 derived classes of Land: SteepyLand, PlanLand, WetLand? What are the deciding factors to make the right choice?

Comment: What are the behaviors of `Land`? Does it have any methods?

Comment: Is the functionality of ‘Land’ totally different between the types? If you will go with enum you will have an “if else” or ‘switch case’ all over? If not go with enum, if so, maybe strategy or composition are more suitable

Comment: @jaco0646, edited the question: "Only difference among them is - when a "Tank" visits these lands, it incurs different cost based on Land type."

Answer (score 2):

If the class is just a plain data structure, you can go with the enum: all kind of land share the same attributes, therefore using polymorphism wouldn't add value.

But if e.g. a wet land needs additional and specific attributes than you could use inheritance to create the more specialized data type and thus enable polymorphism.
Same when `Land` will have operations that require a specific implementation or are special to a certain `LandType` you should use inheritance.

Also if you need extensibility consider inheritance: there are enums that won't change in future, e.g. the enum 'Playback' could contain values 'Next', 'Previous' and 'Current' and they won't change because there are no others. In this case expressing the type of land by using an enum works well. But we can imaging a lot of different 'LandTypes' so changing or extending the enum is more likely to happen. To avoid this modification of `LandType` you could implement a new subtype instead. For example many frameworks and libraries do this for their exceptions: instead of modifying an internal class to provide new flags you are forced to supply your custom Exception by inheriting from a public base type e.g. `Exception`.

Imaging iterations over your `Land` objects where you want to exclude any `Land` where `LandType` is 'Wet', your result would be 'Steepy' and 'Plain'. But when adding a new value 'Rocky' to your `LandType` enum, and don't change all your filters, you will get 'Steepy', 'Plain' and 'Rocky'. This might brake your code everywhere where 'Rocky' is not expected or should be excluded like you excluded 'Wet' from your results. You don't want to change your existing code anytime you add a new `LandType`. So a specific implementation of a new type of `Land` would help to avoid breaking existing code.

Edit:
"...when a "Tank" visits these lands, it incurs different cost based on Land type": because you are asking about design I recommend something like visitor pattern to you to avoid bloating switch-statements.